# PHPExcel not writing any file

Tags: php, file, output, phpexcel

I'm able to read data from any excel file, but when ever I try to write some data into an excel file the php file doesn't work..

A code I tried:

```
<?php
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$fileType = 'Excel2007';
$fileName = 'output.xlsx';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'World!');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
$objWriter->save($fileName);
?>
```

Comment: Error messages? Exceptions thrown by the writer? You don't have any error handling at all. Do the Test scripts work? Directory permissions?

Comment: No error messages or anything... and the test scripts are not working.... But I'm able to read data...

Comment: Have you checked server logs? Have you checked directory permissions? Can you write a simple text file using fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()?

Answer (score 0):

Change 'output.xlsx' destination folder to full permissions 777